# Apache Solrでindexを除外する方法を知りたい

Tags: solr

```
SOLR_HOME/bin/solr -c myindex ~/Documents
```

でindexを生成できますが、~/Documents以下で特定のファイルをindexから除外する方法を知りたい

環境
Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)
Apache Solrバージョン：8.3.0